# Expo Go app keeps crashing since the last update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building an expo based application and I normally use both the Expo Go android app and the Android stimulator on my PC. Both became useful as I tried to build notification features in the app. I needed the Expo Go android app to test my notification since it works only a physical device.
However, since the last update, the app crashes on app start. If I start my project, it crashes. Though the project runs very well on the stimulator.
I have tried to search for the older version of Expo Go app since I can see that it is a global issue and I don't know when they would resolve it. Unfortunately, my phone has refused to install the older version. Any way around this as I need to test the notification feature? It does not show any error.

Comment: Which version are you on?

Comment: Verson 2.28.4 and I have tried to install previous versions, my phone is rejecting it. Keeps telling me 'App not installed'.

Comment: Only the latest version installs in my phone. Any older version doesnt install.